# Why can't I use "SupportedOSPlatform" attribute in my .net Standard 2.0 library?

Tags: .net, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

Why can't I use "SupportedOSPlatform" attribute in my .NET Standard 2.0 library?

The compiler doesn't recognize this attribute.

According to docs:

> Mark the call as Windows-specific. In some cases, it might make sense to mark the calling member as platform-specific via [SupportedOSPlatform("windows")].

Comment: Related feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Support-SupportedOSPlatformAttribute-an/10572666

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need .NET 5 for it. See [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.versioning.supportedosplatformattribute?view=net-5.0#applies-to)

> Applies to
>
> .NET  5.0, 6.0 preview 3

Related docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/code-analysis/5.0/ca1416-platform-compatibility-analyzer

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is there an equivalent attribute for .net standard libraries? Of I am just stuck with conditionals: OperatingSystem.IsWindows()

Comment: I think you need the conditional indeed